# How to understand hadoop mapred.min.split.size and minSplitSize?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In hadoop mapreduce, when setting the number of maps in the map phase, you need to set mapred.min.split.size, but when looking at the official documentation, there is another parameter that is ”minSplitSize”. What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all "mapred.min.split.size" is deprecated in favor of "mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize
"
according to [hadoop docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html).

Nevertheless, "mapred.min.split.size" is used to configure you hadoop cluster in xml config files, while "minSplitSize" is used in setMinSplitSize method of [FileInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html#setMinSplitSize-long-) class to set the value directly in your job configuration programmatticaly and specific to one single job.

Good luck